# How come a variable with type undefined when divided with type object gives a type number?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to divide a variable with type "**UNDEFINED**" and other variable with type "OBJECT" and I was storing the value of the division in the third parameter and when i was checking the type for the third parameter it was showing number.

So can somebody explain me the problem.

```html
<html>

<head>
  HELLO!!!
  <script>
    var a;
    var b = null;
    var c = a / b;
    console.log(typeof a);
    console.log(typeof b);
    console.log(typeof c);
  </script>

  <body>

  </body>
</head>
```

Comment: c would be `NaN` - which, ironically has the type `Number` even though `NaN` stands for `Not a Number`

Comment: The result of division is [*defined*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-div-operator) as always being a number. If the result is nonsensical, then NaN is returned (which is Type Number).

Answer (score 4):

IN javascirpt `NULL` is considered as `+0` in js if you divide `'undefined'` by `0` then you will get `NaN` which is type of `number`.
You are dividing `undefined` with `null` so you are getting `NaN`
Finally your expression will be

```
c = undefined/0; //It will return NaN
```

You can check if result is `NaN` which type is `number`

```
    var a;
    var b = null;
    var c = a / b;
    console.log(typeof a);
    console.log(typeof b);
    console.log(typeof c);
    console.log(Number.isNaN(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

When applying a [multiplicative operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-multiplicative-operators) (one of `* % /`) the operands are first converted to numbers using [ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber).

In the case of

```
var a;
var b = null;
var c = a / b;
```

then [when evaluating](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) `a / b`:

```
ToNumber(a) => ToNumber(undefined) => NaN
ToNumber(b) => ToNumber(null) => +0
```

then [when applying the `/` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-div-operator) at step 1:

> If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.

so:

```
NaN / +0 => NaN
```

and NaN is [Type Number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type).